# Graal VM build error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.Set.iterator()" because "triggers" is null

Tags: java, spring-boot, graalvm, spring-native

Getting following error while running native graal build for my Spring boot project (migrating to Graal VM). I could not find any working answer to this problem anywhere. Requesting the community to help.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.Set.iterator()" because "triggers" is null
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.ReachabilityHandlerFeature.processReachable(ReachabilityHandlerFeature.java:173)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.ReachabilityHandlerFeature.duringAnalysis(ReachabilityHandlerFeature.java:128)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.lambda$runPointsToAnalysis$10(NativeImageGenerator.java:770)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.FeatureHandler.forEachFeature(FeatureHandler.java:86)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.lambda$runPointsToAnalysis$11(NativeImageGenerator.java:770)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.pointsto/com.oracle.graal.pointsto.AbstractAnalysisEngine.runAnalysis(AbstractAnalysisEngine.java:179)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.runPointsToAnalysis(NativeImageGenerator.java:767)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.doRun(NativeImageGenerator.java:582)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.run(NativeImageGenerator.java:539)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.buildImage(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:408)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.build(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:612)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.start(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:134)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:94)
```

Spring Boot version: 3.1.1
JDK: Graal VM, JDK 17
Platform: MacOS (M2, Aarch64)

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>build-native</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile-no-fork</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-native</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <fallback>false</fallback>
                    <buildArgs>
                        <arg>
                            --verbose
                            -Dspring.aot.enabled=true
                            -H:TraceClassInitialization=true
                            -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces
                            -H:Name=trace-app
                            -H:DashboardDump=trace-app
                            -H:+DashboardAll
                            -H:Class=com.xxx.trace.TraceApplication
                            --initialize-at-build-time=org.slf4j.LoggerFactory,ch.qos.logback,org.slf4j.MDC,org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
                            --initialize-at-run-time=io.netty
                            -Dspring.graal.remove-unused-autoconfig=true
                            -Dspring.graal.remove-yaml-support=true
                        </arg>
                    </buildArgs>
                    <agent>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <defaultMode>Standard</defaultMode>
                        <options>
                            <trackReflectionMetadata>true</trackReflectionMetadata>
                        </options>
                        <metadataCopy>
                            <disabledStages>
                                <stage>test</stage>
                            </disabledStages>
                            <merge>true</merge>
                            <outputDirectory>/tmp/test-output-dir</outputDirectory>
                        </metadataCopy>
                    </agent>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This a known bug with / in the Graal 22.x native image builder; see https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/5868.

At the time of writing, no fix is available.  However, you may be able to figure out a work-around based on the issue's correspondence.

Apparently the bug is related to the new `RunReachabilityHandlersConcurrently` option added in Graal version  22.  One possible work-around might be to use an older version of Graal.  Another is to figure out what is using the new option and change it ... as they have done with `googleapis/gax-java` according to https://github.com/googleapis/gax-java/pull/1815.